# Multiple image background on one page only

Tags: html, css

I actually have three problems, but I believe they are all related to trying to place the two images within the same background.  I only need this to appear on one page only.  1) The image on the left is XXpx away from the edge, but the image on the right is butt up against the edge.  2) The footer is appearing between the bottom 25% or so of the two images instead of being at the bottom of the page.  3) I cannot get the size of the images to change, so that each is the same.

**HTML**

```
<body class="homepage">
</body>
<footer>
  <h5 class id="footer">&copy; BPA Productions 2018</h5>
</footer>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.homepage {
   background-image: url(pagepics/emmy.png), url(pagepics/big_oscar.png);
   background-position: left, right;
   background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat; 
   padding: 250px;
}
```

Comment: 1) Are you sure the edges of both images are flush? That is, are you sure the left image isn't off-center to the right. 2) Fix your footer to the bottom or give the rest of your page a height of 100% 3) Use background-size: 150px, 150px in the CSS to make both images 150px.

Comment: 1) I'm pretty sure both images are flush as there is nothing in the code that would move the one on the left.  2) Make the footer position absolute?  3) Adding the size code made the image on the left super small.

Comment: That's not what I mean. I was asking if you are certain that the images you are using are flush with their borders. Meaning that the one you are using on the left side of your page is all the way on the left side of the image itself and there is no empty space on the left edge. And if the 150px size makes the image small, then use a bigger size. That was just an example.

Comment: My bad.  Yes, both images are flush with their borders.  The 150px only made one image small, so just adjust accordingly until they are both approx the same size?

Comment: With two images the background-size attribute takes two arguments so make sure you have "150px, 150px" to make both images 150px, or whatever size you want them to be (could also be in percentages, not just pixels). Without seeing your images myself, I can't tell you what the problem is with getting them flush to both sides, but it has to be with the images themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understand what I mean, but if what you need is just a background image per page, it would be easier to do with conditions in JS, the background may be added according to the page or add classes via JS so create calls in CSS for these classes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".homepage").css({})
});
```

our

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".homepage").addClass("yourClass")
});
```

But I may not have understood your need either, so much so that I could no longer write in the code for not having more information.

Comment: I need both images to appear as the background on one page

Comment: But you want them to switch between them? There is no way for one image to appear on the other unless they have transparency

Comment: No, both appear on the same background.  I have achieved that much, just having the problems that I stated in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, it looks like you're trying to place an image on each side of the background, each taking up half of the screen. I have a solution that works with all modern browsers (tested my versions of IE, Edge, Chrome, and Firefox).

```css
.homepage {
   background-image: url(https://placeimg.com/480/640/tech), url(https://placeimg.com/480/640/people);
   background-position: left, right;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 50.1%;
   padding: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="homepage">
</div>
<footer>
  <h5 class id="footer">&copy; BPA Productions 2018</h5>
</footer>
```

If the 'emmy' and 'grammy' .png files are awards with transparency, the `background-size` property is okay to set at 50%. On some browsers, there is a small amount of space that appears when not set to 50.1% which creates a minuscule overlap. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, both images are transparent.  Every little bit helps as I am stumped.  That code made one statuette HUGE,  the other about half the size it was.  Footer problem is solved though.  :)

Answer (score 0):

If your images need to be the same size, you can specify the sizes in the CSS.

Footer can be positioned absolute, 0 from left, 0 from right, an 0 from bottom.

```
    .homepage {
        background-image: url(pagepics/emmy.png), url(pagepics/big_oscar.png));
        background-position: left, right;
        background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
        background-size: 400px, 400px;
        /*
        Or like so:
        background-size: 400px 100px, 400px 100px;
        */
        padding: 250px;
    }

    footer {
        background-color: #333;
        height: 60px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
```